# Finding the longest contiguous subsequence in an array

Tags: java, arrays

My assignment is to write a program that finds the longest increasing contiguous subsequence in a given array and prints both the length of that subsequence, and the subsequence it self.
Say the array is:

```
int[] arr = {3, 6, 5, 1, 9, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1}
```

The longest continuous increasing subsequence is 2, 3, 4, 5 with a length of 4. 
So the output of this method would be

```
4
2, 3, 4, 5
```

This is my code so far:

```
public class LongestSubsequence {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Test arrays
    int[] arrC = {9, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int[] arrA = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7};
    int[] arrB = {7, 6, 5, 4, 1, 2};
    int[] arr = {3, 6, 5, 1, 9, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1};

    longestForward(arr);

  }

  // input of the int array, returns nothing.
  public static void longestForward(int[] arr) {
    // variables for Length of longest subsequence found and for the length of the current sequence
    int subSeqLength = 1;
    int longest = 1;
    boolean longestSub = false;
    int indexStart = 0;
    int indexEnd = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
      //Increases subsequence length variable 
      if (arr[i] < arr[i+1]) {
        subSeqLength++;
      }
      // Sets the current subsequence to the longest variable if it is the longest one found at the time.
      else if (subSeqLength > longest) {
        longest = subSeqLength;
        longestSub = true;
      }
      // if the current sequence being analyzed is the longest one, keeps track of where it starts and ends
      else if (longestSub = true) {
        arr[i] = indexStart;
        arr[i+1] = indexEnd;
      }
      // sets the subsequence length back to one if it is no longer increasing         
      else subSeqLength = 1;
    }

    System.out.println(subSeqLength);
    System.out.println(indexStart);
    System.out.print(indexEnd);
  }
}
```

So I've figured out how to get the program to identify the length of the longest subsequence. However, I'm stuck on how I can actually get it to print. Right now, I'm just trying to get the method to correctly print the place in the array where the longest subsequence starts and ends. This is not what needs to be in the program, but I thought I would need to figure this out before going on to printing it.

I reasoned that to print the subsequence, I would need to keep track of when the longest sequence started and ended, and from there get the program to print on those elemennts. But my code doesn't seem to be running correctly. There are no errors given, it just runs but doesn't return anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why not just create a function that returns the longest contiguous subsequence (or the first such subsequence if more than one maximal length contiguous subsequence exists)? Then, you can just do `subSequence.length` (or whatever) to get its length.

Comment: Just another way of implementing the same thing. See if you get any tips from this : http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-longest-arithmetic-progression-algorithm/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "create a function". Do you mean create a helper method that returns the correct array and gives it to my longestForward method, which in turn gives it to my main method? If so, how would I go about that? I've tried so many iterations of this code to track what I want but I just can't figure it out. Could I get a start?

Comment: Why do you need `longestForward` to be of `void` type? Why not just do the printing in `main`?

Comment: And yes, by function, I mean method.

Comment: The assignment is annoyingly specific: ", implement longestForward, a method which takes an int array as input, and returns no output.
This method prints two lines of text. The first line is a number, which is the length of the LICS. The
second line is the actual elements of the subsequence itself, separated by commas. In case there are
multiple LICSs of the same length, print the first one"

Comment: It must return no output. So I have to code it from there.

Comment: Okay, well, inside the method, grab the longest consecutive subsequence. Then, just print its length on one line and print the sequence on the next line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here I fixed your algorithm with comments :

```
public static void longestForward(int[] arr)
{
    int subSeqLength = 1;
    int longest = 1;
    int indexStart = 0;
    int indexEnd = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1] - 1)//We need to check if the current is equal to the next
        {
            subSeqLength++;//if it is we increment
            if (subSeqLength > longest)//we assign the longest and new bounds
            {
                longest = subSeqLength;
                indexStart = i + 2 - subSeqLength;//make sure the index start is correct
                indexEnd = i + 2;
            }

        } 
        else
            subSeqLength = 1;//else re-initiate the straight length
    }


    for (int i = indexStart; i < indexEnd; i++)//print the sequence
        System.out.println(arr[i] + ", ");        
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you! It prints the longest array perfectly. I added a bit to make it fit the assignment but it's correct. Thank you!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard what if components of the sequence are not growing arithmetically by 1?

Comment: @zubergu I tought this is what OP wanted, just change the equals to higher than.

Comment: zubergu, that's what I changed in my code. I simply changed the '==' to '<' and removed the -1.

Comment: Another question though, how would I search the original array BACKWARDS without reversing the array? I tried setting the counter variable to the arr.length -1 but I'm still getting an out of bounds error. Any ideas?

Comment: @Zephyr start from array.length, until 1 step by i--. check for arr[i] == arr[i - 1]

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard, I hate to bother you once more but I have one more thing to debug from my code. I can't seem to print out the backwards array now. Could you take a look at [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683015/searching-an-array-backwards-for-longest-contiguous-subsequence) (at the bottom of the question is the code in question) and help me figure out why it won't print the subequence like it did in the first method? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
arr[i] = indexStart;
arr[i+1] = indexEnd;
```

You want it to go the other way, assignment operator assigns value from right to left, but you probably know that already.
But it's not the biggest problem, your code is wrong and can't give you correct answer and there are a few problems.

First of all, forementioned indexStart and indexEnd. You want to store indexes of your array but you actually try to store values in those cells.

Also, keeping track of end of you subsequence should be done every time your subsequence length increases. You `if/else if` logic is wrong and you have to improve it. While you're on it, `isLongest` is never false after being true once, that's bad. You need to check if this is the longest subsequence only when it ends, so when you first `if` is false.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
      if (arr[i] < arr[i+1]) {
        subSeqLength++;
      } else {
        if ( subSeqLength > longest ) {
        indexStart = i - subSeqLength + 1;
        longest = subSeqLength;
        }
        subSeqLength = 1;
      }
    }

    System.out.println(longest);
    System.out.println(indexStart);
    System.out.println(indexStart + longest-1);
```

Comment: Ah. Well spotted. The code runs now. Unfortunately it's not returning the correct values for anything. When I comment out the index else if loops, it returns the correct length value  (but not the correct indexStart and End values). Still stuck.

Comment: After Jean-Francois's answer, I compared his else if logic to mine. I think I spotted my mistake. I went wrong with the boolean, and my code tracked the end erratically, not incrementing it with every iteration. Thank you for your helpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer in JS

```
function longestContigousSubsequence(seq) {

    // to pointers to point at the current and next
    var count; 
    var j;
    var i = 0;
    var result = 0;
    var temp = [];
    var final = []

    // if array length is 1, return the empty array

    while(i < seq.length - 1){
        count = 0;
        j = i + 1;

        temp.push(seq[i])
        while(seq[i] < seq[j] && j < seq.length){
            count += 1;  
            temp.push(seq[j])
            j += 1
            i += 1      
        }

        if(count > result){
            result = count;
            final = temp;
        }

        i += 1;
        temp = [];
        //console.log(i + " " + count);
    }
    return final;

}
```