# Searching an Array backwards for longest contiguous subsequence

Tags: java, arrays

This is a follow-up question to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679991/finding-the-longest-contiguous-subsequence-in-an-array).

I'm looking to find the longest contiguous sequence in an array that is searched backwards.

Thank you for any and all help.

This is my current method:

```
 public static void longestBackward(int[] arr)
  {

    int subSeqLength = 1;
    int longest = 1;
    boolean longestSub = false;
    int indexStart = 0;
    int indexEnd = 0;

    for (int i = arr.length-1; i > 0; i--)
    { // We need to check if the current is equal to the previous
        if (arr[i] < arr[i-1])
        {   // if it is we increment the length
            subSeqLength++;
            // Assign the longest to the current subsequence if it's the longest
            if (subSeqLength > longest)
            {
                longest = subSeqLength;
                longestSub = true;
            }
            // We set the new index end if it is the longuest

            if (longestSub)
            {
                indexStart = i + 2 - subSeqLength;
                indexEnd = i + 2;
            }

        }
        // Else re-initiate the length
        else
            subSeqLength = 1;
    }

    System.out.println(longest);

    // Print the sequence
    for (int i = indexEnd; i < indexStart; i--)
        System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");        
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code and commented in it what I changed :

```
public static void longestBackward(int[] arr) {

    int subSeqLength = 1;
    int longest = 1;
    int indexStart = 0;
    int indexEnd = 0;

    /**
     * We iterate while we are higher then 0 not 1 as we retrieve i - 1
     */
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i - 1]) {//I've changed < to > remember we are backward. 
            subSeqLength++;

            /*
             * I've removed the longestSub which is useless
            */
            if (subSeqLength > longest) {
                longest = subSeqLength;
                indexStart = i + (subSeqLength - 1); //notice that I modified the bounds
                indexEnd = i - 1;
            }
        } // Else re-initiate the length
        else {
            subSeqLength = 1;
        }
    }

    // Print the sequence
    for (int i = indexStart - 1; i > indexEnd; i--) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
    }
}
```

Make sure you comment if there is some part of it you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (arr[i-1] < arr[i - 2])
```

In the first line, i can be 0. In the Third, i-1 would be -1, which is out of bounds for an array. You might want to write `i>1`, or similar.

Have you tried simply reversing the array, and then feeding the reversed array into your original, working method?

Comment: The assignment says I'm not allowed to reverse the array. I have to analyze it backwards.

Comment: Also, I see that mistake. Thank you! However, even changing that ot make sure it isn't zero, I still get an out of bounds error.

Comment: Carefully look at the line that the error occurs on. The error will give you the line number.

Comment: It says the error occurs in line 67, which is the (arr[i+1] < arr[i]) line. But I thought I fixed that. It also says there's an error in line 12, but I assume that's because I call the method and the method has a bug. What's teh issue then?

Comment: Turns out an iteration I tried worked and I didn't even notice. The line should read: (arr[i] < arr[i-1]). Thank you for your help. I figured it out!

Comment: THe only problem now is that it's printing the array backwards. I think that has something to do with my indexStart and End variables.

Comment: Start at the indexEnd, end at the indexStart, and use i--, just like you did for the other for loop.

Comment: Well now it's not printing the array at all. I've editted my post to reflect what I have right now. To me everything looks fine. I don't understand why it's not printing. Did I miss a variable?